# Any other site like Codingbat.com for online java practice?

Tags: java

is here anyone know about codingbat.com? i found it is very useful, because it offers lot of java problems to practice java online and i did most of them. Is there any other site like that, which offers an opportunity to do practicing java?

Comment: Check out https://www.learneroo.com/modules or coderbyte.

Answer (score 1):

You could also find the [Black Belt Factory Exams](http://www.blackbeltfactory.com/TestDefListing.wwa) interesting. Although it is more in direction of testing your knowledge of the language itself or special technoligies surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) and write your solutions in Java, although those problems are more mathematics-oriented and not (directly) about learning a particular language.

Comment: Note that solving some of the more advanced questions _will_ learn you about limitations and workarounds in any language or platform. See for instance problem 282 dealing with the Ackermann function.

Comment: project euler is too narrow - its mostly math(20% of soft dev) -> number theory(0.5% of soft dev). avoid project euler !

Answer (score 0):

Try [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/Algorithm+Overview). It will allow you to try your hand at solving problems in Java or C++. 
It's really educational.

Answer (score 0):

I used Project Euler back in the day, but this site always looked interesting: http://codegolf.com/.